# How to stop threads, once there is no more data in Chan to process?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, channel

I would like to use [Control.Concurrent.Chan](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html). There is a large list, which is split up into smaller lists by the provider. It writes this chunks to the channel. Then the consumers read these chunks from the channel and process them.

How is it possible to close the forks and return the result, once there is no more data to provide and consume?

With `TChan` it is possible to check if the channel is empty. But I would like to learn, how to use simple `Chan`

Most of the example codes I find simply uses `forever $ getLine ...`, and start it from main, where it is not an issue, if a fork is not finished, because once the main ends, the forks will also end. I haven't found a good consumer-provider example yet, from which I could understand, how to work with Chans

Comment: Maybe wrap your data in another type, e.g. `data Message a = WorkPackage a | Done`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can design your channel on base `Chan` like this:

```
newtype MChan a = MChan (Chan (Maybe a))

newMChan :: IO (MChan a)
newMChan = MChan <$> newChan

closeMChan :: MChan a -> IO ()
closeMChan (MChan c) = writeChan c Nothing

writeMChan :: MChan a -> a -> IO ()
writeMChan (MChan c) = writeChan c . Just

readMChan :: MChan a -> IO (Maybe a)
readMChan (MChan c) = readChan c
```

So, you can close channel and consumer will be get Nothing and it will be signal for stop thread.